# autoNumeric.js return currency on keyup on orchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `autoNumeric.js`

I have live calculator. When I type on form to change input values it only return me the symbol when I focus on the calculated field, not triggering my events.

This is how I init `autoNumeric.js`

```
  $('.myInput').autoNumeric('init', { currencySymbol : '₸' , currencySymbolPlacement: "p", decimalPlacesOverride: "0"});
```

I do check listeners

```
$(".calculate").bind('keyup change', function() {

//my calculations

});
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called updated for those want to make live calculator

$('#sum-1').autoNumeric("update" ,{});